# How can I calculate the probability of model $g_i$ given a set of $n$ models and AIC values?

Tags: probability, model-selection, maximum-likelihood

### Background

I have a data set $Y$:

```
set.seed(0)
predictor <- c(rep(5,10), rep(10,10), rep(15,10), rep(20,10)) + rnorm(40)
response  <- c(rnorm(10,1), rnorm(10,4), rnorm(10,2), rnorm(10,1))
plot(predictor, response)
```

and a set of models g$_i$:

```
fits <- list()
fits[['null']]      <- lm(response ~ 1)
fits[['linear']]    <- lm(response ~ poly(predictor, 1))
fits[['quadratic']] <- lm(response ~ poly(predictor, 2))
fits[['cubic']]     <- lm(response ~ poly(predictor, 3))
fits[['Monod']]     <- nls(response ~ a*predictor/(b+predictor), 
                          start = list(a=1, b=1))
fits[['log']]       <- lm(response ~ poly(log(predictor + 1), 1))
```

### Problem

I can find the best fit using

```
library(plyr)    
ldply(fits, AIC)
```

I am revising a manuscript with results originally presented as raw AIC values, but I find the actual AIC values are fairly uninformative and difficult to interpret

### Question

Can I calculate the probability of each model given the set of models e.g. g$_i$ $$\frac{P(Y|\textrm{g}_i)}{\sum_{j=1:n}P(Y|\textrm{g}_j)}$$

An approach that most similar to using AIC wins, because I would like to minimize the amount of revisions to the methods and results that will be required.

### Other considerations:

1. I have considered using ANOVA although this does not appear to have as straightforward of an interpretation as the above, or does it?:

   ```
   anova(fits[[1]],fits[[2]],fits[[3]],fits[[4]],fits[[5]],fits[[6]])
   ```
2. A Bayesian approach would require more work on both implementing statistics and because it would fundamentally change the interpretation from the likelihood interpretation of $P(Y|g)$ to the Bayesian $P(g|Y)$.

Comment: I think you have your 'quadratic' and your 'cubic' models mixed up.

Comment: @David If the $g_i$ are the models and $Y$ is the data, your question already is Bayesian, because it requires a prior and Bayes' theorem to compute $\Pr(g_i|Y)$.

Comment: @David It's legitimate to use AIC for *nested* model comparison (as in null - linear - quadratic - cubic), but not (AFAIK) for completely different models, such as "monod" versus "log".

Comment: @whuber sorry, I got these backwards since my recent work has been in a Bayesian framework that considers data fixed and models variable. But the underlying point- that I would prefer to retain the original likelihood-based approach, remains.

Comment: @David With the fix it looks like Bayes' Theorem but you have omitted the (requisite) prior probabilities for the models.  Once you specify that prior you can obtain (in the usual way) a posterior distribution for the models based on the data.

Comment: @whuber I think that is exactly my problem. I was just hoping that there was a more direct way to estimate these probabilities from AIC (or another penalized likelihood like BIC if that is more appropriate for this set of models). I think that Aikake weights provide something along these lines, but I am still not sure of the interpretation. I'll post an answer describing this in more detail.

Comment: I'm going to agree with whuber. If you put a non informative discrete uniform prior on the models, then the posterior likelihood of model k given data is proportional to the likelihood of the data under the model k. This seems much  simpler then trying to derive an approximation of posterior model likelihoods from AIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although AIC may not be suitable in this context, Aikake weights provide the ratio of $$\frac{L(g_i|Y)}{\sum_{j=1:n}{L(g_j|Y)}}$$

### Solution

This can be calculated from AIC in this way for each model $i$ (closely following [Burnham and Anderson, 2002](http://books.google.com/books?id=BQYR6js0CC8C&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=burnham+and+anderson+akaike&source=bl&ots=i8bVidhbWF&sig=8-a_gaD1QiL_JoPICrzqA_gDyJM&hl=en&ei=AwYVTYunPIeenAfSyIi8CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

$$\Delta_i = AIC_i - AIC_{min}$$

where $AIC_{min}$ is the best fit model

normalizing these by the sum of the likelihoods gives the Aikake Weight ($W_i$) for each model

$$W_i=\frac{exp(-1/2\Delta_i)}{\sum_{j=1:n}{exp(-1/2\Delta_j)}}$$

which [Johnson and Olmland (2004)](http://faculty.washington.edu/skalski/classes/QERM597/papers/Johnson%20and%20Omland.pdf) interpret as

> the probability that model *i* is the best model for the observed data given the candidate set of models.

Burnham and Anderson state that this approach applies for AIC$_c$, QAIC, QAIC$_c$, and TIC.

### References

- Johnson and Olmland, 2004. Model selection in ecology and evolution. TREE 19(2) dx.doi.org/doi:10.1016/j.tree.2003.10.013
- Burnham, K.P. and Anderson, D.R. (2002) Model Selection and Multimodel Inference: A Practical Information-Theoretic Approach, Springer

Comment: This approach seems implicitly to place a uniform prior on the models you are using.  Whether that's appropriate or not depends on the application.

Comment: @whuber That is pretty much what I am going for; I have plenty of data for informative priors on these models but that would be another paper altogether. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: AIC can also be used as (approximate) Bayesian model probabilities with non uniform model prior.  By using BIC to approximate the likelihood $P(D|M_i I)\propto\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}BIC_i\right)$, and then with the prior for the ith model is given by $P(M_i|I)=N^{\frac{d_i}{2}}\exp(-d_i)$, where $d_i$ is the dimension of model $i$.  We get posterior probability of $P(M_{i}|DI)\propto\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}AIC_i\right)$